# Compare two text in javascript from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

const res = ['a','b','c','d'];

I want to show like this from an array dynamically

// a b

// a c

// a d

// b c

// b d

// c d

is it possible?

Advance thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can have two for loops to loop through each element of the array and the inner loop should start with the next value of the outer loop to consider the starting from the next element for the second position.

```js
const res = ['a','b','c','d'];

for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  for (var j = i+1; j < res.length; j++) {
    console.log(res[i], res[j])
  }
}
```